# With Python, how to use smbclient to check remote folder/file existence

Tags: python, path, exists, smb

What I try to do is I want to check my_new_folder exists or not with smbclient first before I create it.

```
import smbclient
username = 'username'        # Domain user name 
password = "password"        # Domain user password

smbclient.register_session(server="remote_server_name", username=username, password=password, port=445,auth_protocol='ntlm')
new_shared_subfolder_path="//remote_server_name/existing_shared_folder/my_new_folder"
## How to check new_shared_subfolder_path exists or not with smbclient, before I create it?  
smbclient.mkdir(new_shared_subfolder_path)
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. try to use makedirs

## if my_new_folder does not exist, then create it

smbclient.**makedirs**(my_new_folder , **exist_ok=True**)

2.

## check file existence

print(smbclient.path.exists(file_path))

## check whether the path is a folder

print(smbclient.path.isdir(file_path))

Comment: Please read [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)